# How do I replace __asm jno no_oflow with an intristic in a VS2008 64bit build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, intrinsics

I have this code:

```
__asm jno no_oflow
overflow = 1;
__asm no_oflow:
```

It produces this nice warning:

> error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '__asm' keyword not supported on this architecture

What would be an equivalent/acceptable replacement for this code to check the overflow of a subtraction operation that happened before it?

Comment: After a while we got bitten in this area either way - turns out it's not so good to check for overflow this way either way - the nicest description and solutions I've found are here: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow?showComments=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define the following:

```
#ifdef _M_IX86
typedef unsigned int READETYPE;
#else
typedef unsigned __int64 READETYPE;
#endif

extern "C"
{
READETYPE __readeflags();
}

#pragma intrinsic(__readeflags)
```

You can then check the eflags register as follows:

```
if ( (__readeflags() & 0x800))
{
    overflow = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this solves it and leaves the functionality basically identical! - I think it's enough to just include <intrin.h> and use readeflags - also I'll change 0x800 to ( 1 << 11 ) to make it a bit more readable

Comment: Good links for future reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983406%28VS.80%29.aspx, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register_%28computing%29

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the code above is trying to catch some sort of integer overflow/underflow? Maybe the answers to this question will help: [How to detect integer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5704bbxw.aspx)  of intrinsics available on all platforms. Looks there's nothing suitable there. I guess the most portable way would be to check before the subtraction whether it will lead to an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Microsoft disallowed inline assembly in 64-bit. but you can still write assembly in a separate .asm file, and link your program against it.